# C# WebClient DownloadFile works only once

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, webclient

I built a function that downloads a series of reports from my website (.NET webforms, old application), saves them as .html files in a temporary folder, zips them and return an archive to the user.
The application uses windows authentication and I managed to pass the current user credentials in the request by enabling

```
Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

Everything works seamlessly in my dev environment (both in IIS Express that on IIS), but on production server (Windows server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5) it only works if I limit the cycle to one iteration only. 
It looks like the WebClient underlying connection remains open and the server refuses to open another one on the following cycle.
The error message I get is

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

and, enabling WCF tracing, I can narrow the issue to a "401 unauthorized" error.

Here's the significant part of my function:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
foreach (var project in list.Take(1)) //fails if I try list.Take(2) or more
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient
    {
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    })
    {       
        UriBuilder address = new UriBuilder
        {
            Scheme = Request.Url.Scheme,
            Host = Request.Url.Host,
            Port = Request.Url.Port,
            Path = "/ERP_ProjectPrint.aspx",
            Query = string.Format("bpId={0}&bpVid={1}", project.Id, project.VersionId)
        };
        string fileName = project.VersionProtocol + ".html";
        client.DownloadFile(address.Uri.ToString(), tempFilePath + fileName);       
    }
}
```

Any hint about IIS settings I could tweak to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems to be schannel issue. Since Schannel is out of IIS, I'm not sure if it would be fixed by IIS configuration. Could you enable log and post more error message about this issue？https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/260729/how-to-enable-schannel-event-logging-in-iis Besides, what's the detailed error message in IIS 401? Did you enable load user profiler?

Comment: YES! a schannel error gets logged: "The following fatal alert was generated: 70. The internal error state is 105." Event ID: 36888. I'm investigating...

Comment: It reallys sounds like an schannel issue especially when the code works fine on other people's machine. Have you tried to modify your schannel cipher suite,protocol,etc..with IIS crypto? If you log crash dump for your code, you should be able to view the real inner exception thrwon by WIN32 API.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction! I discovered that TLS 1.2 was disabled on my server (Win2008R2). After enabling it the page worked seamlessly. Unfortunately this somehow broken the RDP connection, so I can't connect to the server anymore. I'm investigating with the datacenter guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved by enabling TLS 1.2 on the server: it wasn't enabled by default. Refer to https://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/.

BE AWARE that enabling it may break the RDP connection functionality to your server.

Thanks to Jokies Ding for pointing me in the right direction (see comments above)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Dispose() is not working correct within the using() statement:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 { ... }
```

Workaround without a using() statement:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileCompleted;
```

when download is completed:

```
client.Dispose()
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving you loop into your request, like below. Does that make a difference?

Also don't think you need to use list.Take

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10

using (WebClient client = new WebClient
{
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
}) 
   {                                         
     foreach (var project in list) 
     {

        UriBuilder address = new UriBuilder
        {
            Scheme = Request.Url.Scheme,
            Host = Request.Url.Host,
            Port = Request.Url.Port,
            Path = "/ERP_ProjectPrint.aspx",
            Query = string.Format("bpId={0}&bpVid={1}", project.Id, project.VersionId)
        };
        string fileName = project.VersionProtocol + ".html";
        client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(address.Uri.ToString(), tempFilePath + fileName).Wait();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've already tried that, but it doesn't make any difference.
Take(2) is there just to limit the amount of reports downloaded, to speed up the debugging

Comment: Didn't work.
Neither this other attempt: 
await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(address.Uri.ToString(), tempFilePath + fileName);

Comment: @Chunk_ITA can you try see if the ServicePointManager setting works - May need to up the number a little